# Vimeo API video upload via Dropzone JS

Tags: jquery, file-upload, dropzone.js, vimeo

I am currently working on a DropzoneJS based uploader for Vimeo. I already read the Vimeo API Upload documentation. I wanted to use the classic POST upload because I do not need a resumable upload for this project.

On the other side, I need a progress bar. I read that it is possible to get progress information without the resumable PUT upload too. So I thought to use the POST request in combination with DropzoneJS.

However, the authentification and the classic HTML5 form upload worked very well, but when I used DropzoneJS there was always an error: "Server responded with 0 code."

Here is my Code:

```
$.post( glob_cms_home_dir+"vimeo/vimeo.php", { //serverside Authentification
    task        : "upload_ticket"
})
.done(function( data ){

    var result = $.parseJSON(data);

    var h_lib_dropzone = new Dropzone("#h_lib_body_upload_dropzone_content", { //clientside Upload

        url: result["upload_link_secure"],
        method: "post",
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        uploadMultiple: false,
        parallelUploads: 1,
        paramName: "file_data",

        acceptedFiles: "video/*",

        init: function(){

            this.on("success", function (file, response) {
                alert(response);
            });
            this.on("error", function (file, error) {
                alert(error);
            });
        }
    });
});

$("#h_lib_nav_upload_action").click(function(){

    h_lib_dropzone.processQueue();
});
```

The HTML form-markup looks like this:

```
<form id="h_lib_body_upload_dropzone_content" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>
```

For me, it looks like the DropzoneJS post request is not the same as the HTML5 post even with same given parameters...

I just started to work with an API yesterday, so I have no experiences with this. I would be very thankful if somebody can help me. :)

Thank you.
Tobi